# Create json tree structure with children

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json tree structure that is appended to by pressing invoke on this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjsfiddlenetuser/C6Ssa/4/

Press invoke multiple tiles on the fiddle & copy/paste the produced jSon intohttp://jsonlint.com/, the produced json is not valid

I need to produce this :

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "url": "asdfas",
            "date": ""
        },
        {
            "url": "asdfas",
            "date": ""
        },
        {
            "url": "asdfasfdasas",
            "date": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Can this be amended so that multiple children can be added to the tree structure, I think I need to amend the var data somehow ?

Comment: I am not clear what you want in output. Can you give a sample of ur expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var data = {nodes: []};

$("#add").on('click', function () {
    data.nodes.push({
        url: "some url",
        date: new Date
    });

    $("#myDiv").text(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

if not, I didn't understand your question ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/gY5yQ/

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps http://jsfiddle.net/C6Ssa/12/

```
var data = [];


$("#add").click(add);
function add() {

data.push({
    param1: "stuff",
    param2:1,
    param3:1
});
var sample = {};
sample.node = data
$("#myDiv").text(JSON.stringify(sample));
}
```